# Iterating through dates over a specific period of time in python

Tags: python, loops

I am currently working with a large dataset that has lists of daily inventory. I want to compare the inventory over 2 days to see what has changed, and continue that process for an entire month. For example for the month of January, I want to see the change between January 1 and 2, and then January 2 and 3, and so on until I reach January 31st.

I was able to write a code to compare inventory between 2 dates. But how do I iterate that process for the code to continue running for the next set of days? I am new to programming and would appreciate any help.

In the code below, I created 2 subsets: the 1st for the inventory on October 14 and the 2nd for inventory on October 15. In the 3rd line, I calculate what has changed between the 2 days using the unique identifier in the dataset (image).

```
cars_date_1 = cars_extract_drop[(df['as_of_date'] > '2015-10-14') &
(df['as_of_date'] < '2015-10-15')]

cars_date_2 = cars_extract_drop[(df['as_of_date'] > '2015-10-15') & 
(df['as_of_date'] < '2015-10-16')]

cars_sold = cars_date_1[~cars_date_1['image'].isin(cars_date_2['image'])]
```

Comment: As a quick side note, you should know that Python supports `if 1 < a < 3:` in lieu of `if a > 1 and a < 3`. Python supports this daisy-chaining of conditions...
Also, instead of hardcoding your dates, you can use variables inside a loop to iterate through all the dates in a month.  If you want to cross month boundaries, you should have a look at some of the date/time modules, like datetime. But if you're in one single month, a formatting statement like `'2015-10-%02d' % i` might do the trick. Really depends on how flexible you need it to be.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html.   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `pd.date_range()` function and iteration through each element:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365, freq='D')


for i in range(365):
    day_1 = rng(i)
    day_2 = rng(i+1)

    difference_function(day_1, day_2)
```